# Random/continuous playing of device-removed and device-added sounds

Tags: sound, notification, devices

I'd like to ask a question about a weird problem I have been experiencing on my 17.10 install.

Basically, every 15s-3min a quick succession of what appears to be

/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/device-removed.oga

and

/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/device-added.oga

plays over the active audio device (either headphones or laptop speakers)

I am unable to track down any device changes in either dmesg or syslog, so I am wondering: what could be causing these spurious notification sounds?

Comment: Me too, UBuntu 17.10, only on physical machine install, not on Virtual Machine. I'm watching this thread closely.

Comment: I found the location you mentioned, and gzipped the files to make them not present. I noticed they were symlinked to from network-connectivity-established.oga network-connectivity-lost.oga power-plug.oga power-unplug.oga .. It could be intermittent network, or power switching on/off to charge a laptop battery maybe? Mine is a laptop on cable, so unlikely to be network.

Comment: I suspect that in my case it might be caused by a laptop AC-DC adapter that's not-quite-failing. AFAIK there is no battery-life-extending technology in the linux world that randomizes charging on and off.